# How to publish an app as hidden in Google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

The company I work for wants me to publish their app as hidden in the Google play store and from what I have found that is not really the case unless a) you create a Google apps work account and invite all clients/staff to join and b) keep it as a beta and use clients/staff as testers. Is it really any other way of publishing an application as hidden (not searchable) and accessible only by link lets say?

Comment: Why do you want to "publish" an app as hidden? What is your purpose behind. Only then we can help you with possible ways. If it's once on googles server it's published. If you want to hide company knowledge you shouldn't even use the beta feature. It depends on your purpose.

Comment: That is what the client wants.

Comment: I'm asking why the client wants that. From your answer it seems it's a requirement. And behind this there must be a reason. The company should clarify this before you can provide a proper solution on that.

Comment: as far as I can tell it is an app only for private use only by the council and don't want other users to have access to it.

Comment: Why not distribute it as apk file on your own web servers where only your staff etc. has permission?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of an app distribution channel. Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) to learn what is and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow regarding the Play Store or other app distribution channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use private [channel for distribution](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)  or check alternative solutions like [crashlytics](https://fabric.io)

Answer (score 1):

Only people who joined the beta test program can download your app. I don't know if you can really hide it from other people because in that case it would be still accessible in other ways such as the package name.
If there is no option for that, then probably that is not possible

But you might be searching for this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en

Edit:

If it is not a requirement to publish the app explicitly on Google Play, then you could upload it to your own web server and only let staff/clients have access to it.
You could then also implement a little updater in the app itself so it is kept updated.
Think about it. I have already made such an updater and it is not difficult to implement it.

Btw, if you don't mind, you may take a look at aptoide.com where you can publish apps but without being visible to other people.

Comment: I am aware of that, I have listed that in my question but still that is what the client wants, no beta testing, no google work accounts etc.

Comment: You probably will have no way around, sorry.